# VS Code C Program Debug Console Not Working

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am learning the C language on macOS using the VS Code IDE.

Below is the C code I am trying to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_from_user;

    /* Get number from user */
    printf("Please enter month number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_from_user);

    /* Print month name */
    switch (number_from_user)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("January");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("February");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("March");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("April");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("May");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("June");
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("July");
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("August");
            break;
        case 9:
            printf("September");
            break;
        case 10:
            printf("October");
            break;
        case 11:
            printf("November");
            break;
        case 12:
            printf("December");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Not a month");
            printf("Please run the program again");
            break;
    }
}
```

Below is the launch.json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem that I am facing is, to make the `scanf` function to work, I need to set `externalConsole` to true. Unfortunately, when I run the code, it does open the terminal but it opens a blank terminal and doesn't actually run the code.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: The code itself is fine although a bit awkward an naive. Try to replace `printf("Please enter month number: ")` with `printf("Please enter month number:\n")`. It this works, then it's a line buffering issue. If not, the problem is within your environment.

Comment: Adding ```\n``` doesn't fix it. Definitely a problem with my environment.

Comment: Does a simple "Hello World" program work?

Comment: When I set ```externalConsole``` to false, ```printf``` works fine but ```scanf``` doesn't apparently because VSCode's debug console cant take in user inputs. So I set ```externalConsole``` to true, and when I do this nothing works.

Comment: As the actual C code is not relevant to the question, your question is more likely to be answered if you simplify your code in order to have a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you do `while(scanf("%d", &number_from_user) != 1){}` instead?

Comment: Again, it just opens up the terminal and doesn't run anything

Answer (score 1):

I installed the plugin code-Runner, normally if you get the gcc already installed and working would be working at the moment you install it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

You just click the play (or run) button, it will opens automatically a console inside the VS-Code and run the actual program.

If the problem is only with `scanf` persists, you can try this
Go to File > Preferences -> User Settings and add custom settings:

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

Here's the source of the explanation:
https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/72

Ps: Be careful, only accepts single file programs, in the beginning is useful, but maybe later would change to others more complex.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thx for the edit! Still need some "sense of style"

Comment: Thanks for this answer, unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. When I press the run button, code runner states that the code is running, but no terminals open. Settings up VSCode for C is a bit of a nightmare, I think I might just use Xcode as it fully supports C

Comment: https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1469-algoritmos/2765-compilando-cc-desde-visual-studio-code-windows-10/
@SidS try to follow this guide, is the one that I used to install it time ago, and the console just open normally.
If the problem still goes, I'm sorry I can't help you without the PC in the hand.